# How can I blur an image on Canvas using fabricjs with React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

I'm new to fabricjs, I've been trying to blur an image using a HTML slider(range from 0 - 1). The image has already been loaded on the canvas. But while applying the blur effect using Filters arrays, I don't see any visible change.

I'm using a controlled blur component in React as follows :

```
<div>
  Blur
    <input
      id="blur"
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="1"
      step="0.1"
      value={editor?.canvas?.getActiveObject()?.filters?.slice(-1)[0]?.blur || 0}
      onChange={(e) => handleChangeSlider("blur", e?.target?.value)}
      ></input>
   <span>{editor?.canvas?.getActiveObject()?.filters.slice(-1)[0]?.blur || 0}</span>
 </div>
```

the onChange handler function is as follows :

```
function handleChangeSlider(){
setBlur(value)
editor?.canvas?.getActiveObject()?.filters?.push({
        blur: 0.5,
        horizontal: false,
        aspectRatio: 1,
      })
// editor?.canvas?.getActiveObject()?.applyFilters()
}
editor.canvas.renderAll()
}
```

The same approach works if I'm setting opacity on the image, like:

```
editor.canvas.getActiveObject().set({ opacity: value })
```

But, as far as I know, the Blur has to be inside the filters array, So I've tried doing the same, but it is not working at all.

Some Observations :

1. Even after doing the `editor.canvas.renderAll()` , I think `editor?.canvas?.getActiveObject()?.applyFilters()` is necessary to apply the blur property. But if I uncomment that line from above code, i get the following error "filter.isNeutralState is not a function" . While that line being kept commented, I don't see any error or any change.
2. I found this [codepen](https://codepen.io/abhinav-anshul/pen/wvmxLvR) link, where the author is literally doing the same, But I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in my case.

My  `editor?.canvas?.getActiveObject()`
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сreate a filter like this:

```
new fabric.Image.filters.Blur({
  blur: 0.5,
  horizontal: false,
  aspectRatio: 1,
});
```

In order to solve the cross-origin issue use the additional parameter:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(
  activeDragDropItem.src,
  function (oImg) {
    oImg.scale(0.2);
    oImg.top = e.nativeEvent.layerY;
    oImg.left = e.nativeEvent.layerX;
    editor.canvas.add(oImg);
  },
  {
    crossOrigin: "",
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think its on right track, but I'm getting a. "The image element contains cross-origin data, and may not be loaded." How can I add cross-origin parameter to this?

Comment: Please, provide more details in your original question. How do you create and render the image?

Comment: Can you please checkout this repo i just created for the above code - https://github.com/abhinav-anshul/fabricjs-editor -Thanks so much

Comment: I have updated the answer. BTW, you are adding too many filters for a blur.

Comment: Amazing, this works as expected. Thanks so much

Comment: Yes, I'm addding too many filters, I need to stop pushing it as object as I'm doing it right now

Comment: Is there any workaround for having too many filters? I'm trying a logic where if I an filter array then change its `blur` value (while moving the slider in the UI), if the value doesn't exist for Blur in the filters array then only push. But this doesn't seem to work as expected